# Crytal Reports - Subreport

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a main report and a group subreport the is driven off of a value in the mainreport.  What I want to do is have the subreport printon a new page without the Headers showing from the main report.  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Clarification requested: do you want to have a page from the main report between these subreports?  For example: Record A, pagebreak, Subreport A, pagebreak, Record B, pagebreak, Subreport B, pagebreak, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, depending on how your report is structured and how it's being viewed (in it's native .rpt format, exported to PDF, etc.).

1. If you're looking for a "Do not print page header/footers if there is a subreport on this page" function, I've never seen one. Sure would be convenient though if it did exist. However, the *InRepeatedGroupHeader* boolean might help you in conditionally suppressing the header/footer sections.  This will take a lot of trial & error, however.
2. If the subreports are that different from the main report, don't try to combine them.  Keep these "subreports" in a completely separate file.
3. Are the page numbers of the subreports locked down? i.e. If you know for certain that these subreports are only 1 page long and appear only on even-numbered pages? In this case, you can 'suppress' page headers and footers only on even-numbered pages.